# Resharper StyleCop SA1306 and casing of Func<T> delegates

Tags: coding-style, resharper, stylecop, capitalization, casing

```cs
public class MyClass
{
    private Func<string, string> KeyTransformer;

    public MyClass(Func<string, string> keyTransformer)
    {
        KeyTransformer = keyTransformer;
    }

    public string DoSomething(string input)
    {
        return KeyTransformer(input);
    }
}
```

Obviously Resharper suggests me to rename the "field" to _keyTransformer.

But it *feels* wrong to write something like that:

```
string newKey = _keyTransformer("input");
```

So question #1 is:
**Pascal casing or camel casing?**

And question #2 is (in case it is pascal):
**How do I tell Resharper it's okay to have pascal casing for Func?**

Comment: Any particular reason you've got a field rather than an autoproperty?

Comment: If he don't want to expose "KeyTransformer" outside of MyClass why he should use autoproperty? Just don't say "private property" :P

Answer (score 0):

Which style is going to be clearer to the next person to read the code?

In this case you're doing something a little unusual (calling a method stored in a field) so the fact the syntax makes it stand out is no bad thing.

Answer (score 0):

It's private field so camel case.

> Rule SA1306 : Variable names and private field names must start with a lower-case letter: {0}.

It's not obvious to (in case of R#) suggest underline.

> Rule SA1309 : Field names must not start with an underscore.

So you have to change behavior of your R# :)
In my case after installing StyleCop (4.7.47) and open project in VS, R# notify my that some rules are not consistent with StyleCop and asked my if I want to change it.
So I have the same rules in R# and StyleCop (eg. naming convention for private fields)

```cs
public class MyClass
{
    private Func<string, string> keyTransformer;

    public MyClass(Func<string, string> keyTransformer)
    {
        this.keyTransformer = keyTransformer;
    }

    public string DoSomething(string input)
    {
        return keyTransformer(input);
    }
}
```